# Why does data transfer over NFC with HCE only work with Android lower 12?

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, hce

I am trying to send data (to keep it simple at first just a NDEF text message) between two Android devices with a React Native App. In order to do that I emulate an NFC tag on one device with the [`react-native-hce`](https://github.com/appidea/react-native-hce) Library and read this tag on the other device with the [`react-native-nfc-manager`](https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager) Library.

Here is the NFC-relevant code:

```javascript
  async function sendData() { 
    const tag = new NFCTagType4({
      type: NFCTagType4NDEFContentType.Text,
      content: 'Hello World',
      writable: true
    });
    session = await HCESession.getInstance();
    session.setApplication(tag);
    await session.setEnabled(true).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  async function stopSending() {
    if(session)
       await session.setEnabled(false)
  }

  async function readNdef() {
    stopSending()
    NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.Ndef)
      .then(() => NfcManager.getTag())
      .then(tag => {
        if(tag) {
          let text = String.fromCharCode(...tag.ndefMessage[0].payload)
          Alert.alert("Message received", text)
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.warn(err)
      })
      .then(() => {NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest()})
  }
```

I tested my app with several devices I got:

**Old Sony Xperia (Android 8), Samsung Galaxy A50 (Android 11), Huawei P30 Lite (Android 11):** Working perfectly fine.

**Motorola Edge 30 Fusion (Android 12), Samsung Galaxy A41 (Android 12):** Not working. HCE just isn't working (without any error) and reading an emulated tag works basically, **but** there is no NDEF message read although it exists (also the App TagInfo is able to read NDEF). With normal, non-emulated tags it works fine.

It seems like Android 12 has problems with reading emulated tags and HCE. Maybe it's a problem of the React Native Libraries? Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Comment: I think it it is a common problem with Android and possibly not the library also reported a problem with Android 12 in a native implementation at https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75676725/2373819 it seems that the Type 4 NFC spec is not clear as it should be on the max size of an Ndef message.

I think that a lot of previous code used `FFFE` as the max size when in fact the max size according to the spec is `80FE` and now Android might be treating the capability container with an invalid max size as bad.

This is a theory as I have no way to test it (I don't have access to an Android 12 or higher device)

**Update**

While the practical limit is `80FE` according to the spec it seems that `7FFF` (or 32K) is a more logical limit and this matches a number that is more likely for a physical Tag's memory size, and comments show some success.

And thus the line

`byte[] controlTlv = BinaryUtils.HexStringToByteArray("0406E104FFFE00" + (prefManager.getWritable() ? "00":"FF"));`

In the [library](https://github.com/appidea/react-native-hce/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativehce/apps/nfc/NFCTagType4.java#L52) should be

`byte[] controlTlv = BinaryUtils.HexStringToByteArray("0406E10480FE00" + (prefManager.getWritable() ? "00":"FF"));`

(also the line `public final byte[] ndefDataBuffer = new byte[0xFFFE];` in the same file should have the same size change)

The library does have an [issue](https://github.com/appidea/react-native-hce/issues/22) for this

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately that didn't fix it for me. I made the changes you suggested but I still cannot read with my Android 12 devices with my app. The weird thing is that the NXP TagInfo App is able to read it. It says "No NDEF data storage populated" but then further down the NDEF file contents is displayed properly. Do you know how TagInfo does that since the "NDEF" tech type just isn't available for me?

Comment: It might be worth trying it with the smaller `7FFF` value that seemed to have success in the other question, even though the spec says that `80FE` is the practical limit. If not then the theory is bust.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Reading is now working with 7FFF on my Motorola (Android 12) and also on Samsung Galaxy S22 (Android 13). Ironically, it doesn't work on the A41 (Android 12) but I think that's another problem. However, HCE still isn't working on all of these, they can't "send" data. Again, thanks a lot for your help.